# self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true) doesn't dismiss any presented view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am working on an app with Swift and Storyboard in Xcode. 2 view controllers are being presented on top of each other, and I want to dismiss them by pressing a button. I already searched here on StackOverflow for an answer, and I found `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)`, but it didn't work. Do you have any ideas on why that couldn't work?

### Solution:

What worked in this case, was just to use another line of code. I don't know what is different, but it somehow worked:

```
self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: are you sure self.navigationController is not nil ?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: @FrederikBrammer Use a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your NavigationController is nil ...

```
if let nav = self.navigationController {
     nav.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
} else {
   print("nav is nil")
}
```

Comment: It says, that nav is nil, how can I fix that?

Comment: Now you need to check why is it so ... are you presenting this controller ?

Comment: Pop is for push ... and for presented controller we have dismiss ...

Comment: Accept if it helps... thanks ... happy coding =)

Comment: I just used a different command, self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) worked for me. I don't know what the differences are, but it somehow worked.